How to optimize sql in large list?
I have a sql as shown below.
SELECT * FROM payment
WHERE is_deleted = 0
    AND is_privacy = 0
    AND ou_code IN ('A1', 'A2', ..., 'W1', 'W2'...)
LIMIT 0, 20

There are many elements after in, about 3,000.payment table has 50 million data, and ou_code, is_deleted, is_privacy all have index. I tried the following methods:
1、use a temporary table: create a new temporary table, insert the ou_code list into the table and create an index, and then use inner join. But my Java application is prohibited from using DDL statements in the program, so I can't try this method.
2、 So I tried to create a temporary table with sql syntax: like below:
SELECT * FROM 
(VALUES ROW('A1'), ROW('A2')... ROW('W1'), ROW('W2')...) tem(`code`)
inner join 
payment
on payment.`ou_code` =  tem.`code`
WHERE is_deleted = 0
    AND is_privacy = 0
LIMIT 0, 20

But this table doesn't seem to be able to create an index, so the efficiency is not improved, but it's slower.
3、use exists: I tried it, but this method cannot create an index either and is even slower.
SELECT *
FROM 
payment
WHERE is_deleted = 0
    AND is_privacy = 0
    AND exists (select 1 from (SELECT 'WA1' AS `code`
UNION ALL  
SELECT 'WA2'  
UNION ALL  
SELECT 'WA3') tem where tem.code = payment.ou_code)
LIMIT 0, 20

4、 full ou code table: I have another idea like this, but it has not been implemented yet. Can you help me analyze whether it is feasible in theory?
The meaning of ou code is company code, so the full amount of ou_code is known, the above list in sql is also part of the full amount.
Can I first create a table with index in advance, insert the full amount of ou_code data, and then use a sql similar to the following?
SELECT payment.* FROM payment
inner join full_ou_code on payment.ou_code = full_ou_code.ou_code
WHERE is_deleted = 0
    AND is_privacy = 0
    AND full_ou_code.ou_code IN ('A1', 'A2', ..., 'W1', 'W2'...)
LIMIT 0, 20

Any idea will be appreciated.

Yes, there is a simple and much better way. Do not use long lists at all. If you need a specific logic or a restriction for a part of your table, create a column or a mapping table.

I agree with your comment @JonasMetzler but perhaps the OP does not have DDL rights.

In this case, they should talk to a person who has the necessary rights and fix or let them fix the DB structure rather than implementing ugly, slow logic.

ALTER TABLE payment ADD KEY oucode_deleted_privacy (ou_code, is_deleted, is_privacy); should resolve it.

@YourCommonSense - Start with the columns tested with =:  INDEX(is_deleted, is_privacy, ou_code)

@RickJames I suppose that cardinality of these particular columns is next to void.

@RickJames also I don't see why ou_code is not tested with = as well.

@YourCommonSense - If there were a single value in the IN-list, it would be =.  But with multiple values, the Optimizer sorts them, then decides whether to hop through the index or punt and turn thing around reach into the sorted list via a binary search.  I don't know the full details.  I consider IN (with multiple values) to be less optimizable than = but sometimes better than a "range" test.

@RickJames for me, x IN(1,2,3) is just a syntax sugar for x=1 OR x=2 OR x=3. So technically it's still =. But I see what you mean. And still, is_deleted and is_private combined shouldn't take more than single percent points. Which makes the efficiency of  index built on them is next to that of fullscan.

@YourCommonSense - Yes, syntactic sugar.  But...  x=1 OR x=2 OR x=3 is turned into x IN(1,2,3) so that the Optimizer can do a few minor optimization tricks.  On the other hand, a=1 OR b=2 OR c=3 is harder to optimize.  Still harder is tbl1.x = 1 OR tbl2.y = 2.

@YourCommonSense - if is_deleted = 0 _eliminates) more than approx. 80% of the rows, any index starting with is_deleted is a good candidate for use.

@RickJames YES, that's what I am talking about. While it should be be like 0.8% with is_private combined. I worked with like half a dozen ecommerce and deleted/private orders occur extremely seldom. So as a rule, this index would have zero canrdinality, unless this particular ecommerce is very specific.

The query is:
SELECT * FROM payment
WHERE is_deleted = 0
    AND is_privacy = 0
    AND ou_code IN ('A1', 'A2', ..., 'W1', 'W2'...)
LIMIT 0, 20

You can optimize this with a compound index on (is_deleted, is_privacy, ou_code), but keep in mind:
The order of columns is important. For the query you show, the column ou_code must be last in that set of columns. For an explanation, see my answer to Does Order of Fields of Multi-Column Index in MySQL Matter
MySQL can optimize long IN() lists, but by default MySQL is configured to cap the amount of memory used during the optimization phase. You can configure this. See my answer to MySQL 'IN' operator on large number of values
Even a single-column index on ou_code may help, but the memory configuration is still needed.
If you don't have the index I described, and you don't have DDL privileges, then you'll have to talk to your database administrator and get them to create the index for you.

I suppose that cardinality of these particular two columns is next to void, hence it would be a hard task to persuade mysql to use such index. And even if so, its performance would be next to fullscan.

Certainly there's no point in the compound index if you put the "is" columns after the ou_code column used for the range scan. Once a column is used in a range condition, the subsequent columns of the index are not used for searching or sorting.

What I mean,there's no point in the compound index if you put is_deleted and is_private orders first, because practically, they shouldn't take more than a few percent points combined. Which will make make the efficiency of such index next to that of fullscan.

You have tested this?

First of all I agree with @Jonas Metzler if you don't have DDL rights you should talk to someone who is able to fix the DB structure.
This is the best way to solve your issue. However for a temporary workaround you could try to batch your IN clauses. This could help you but only little don't expect too much.
With batching I mean something like this
    SELECT * FROM payment
WHERE is_deleted = 0
    AND is_privacy = 0
    AND ou_code IN ('A1', 'A2', ..., 'A500')
LIMIT 0, 20;

-- Next batch...
SELECT * FROM payment
WHERE is_deleted = 0
    AND is_privacy = 0
    AND ou_code IN ('A501', 'A502', ..., 'A1000')
LIMIT 0, 20;

Keep in mind this is quick and dirty pseudo code. There may be syntax error's but should give you an idea of what I mean

I have also tried this method, but the sum of the two execution times is longer than before single execution time.

I don't get how doing in batches should be any better. If I need to fill a bucket, it won't be faster if I do it using a cup instead of filling it at once from the faucet. Batching could only be slower

If you view it like that yes. But you forgot about the analyzer, the lock of server ressources, memory usage, dynamic query optimizer etc. like the whole handler is in theory quicker. As i statet above it COULD not it WILL. It depends on your server and how much power it has. From my experience companies with such... inoptimized DDL tend to buy cheap stuff with low ressources. But again it does not always have to be the case. To read more take a look at this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5636/optimize-large-sql-server-insert-update-and-delete-processes-by-using-batches/

It's you forgot about "the analyzer, the lock of server ressources, memory usage, dynamic query optimizer etc." that are being stressed not once but multiple times per one query.

yes it is stressed multiple times per one query. but the amount does not rise linear to the amount of data sets. how siginficant that exponential rise is depends on the server config and ofc the amount of ressources you have.

In general I understand your point. But the faucet analogy is too simplified for such a complex topic like DB Queryhandling. I get what you are trying to say: Batching can produce overhead. The thing is... that statement is too widely generalized. Yes you are right it can be. But coincidentally it can also be beneficial. Again and i can't stress this enough. It is from usecase to usecase different. There are so many factors that determine if Batching is efficient or even making it worse. OP tested it... it did not work. I had cases where it gave a small benefit and some which didn't.
